# What is the difference between “um” and “am”?

Tags: preposition, time

What is the difference between *um* and *am* when used with times in German?

e.g.

> um 8 Uhr

vs

> am 8 Uhr

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Am 8 Uhr* is wrong, *um 8 Uhr* is correct. The prepositions in use with *times of the day* are

- *um* = exactly that time
- *gegen* = approximately that time
- *vor* = before/in advance
- *nach* = after

The preposition *am* is used instead of *um* for dates e.g. *am 9. April*.

Note that *um […] herum* may also be used for expressing a loose time approximation (e.g. “Er wollte um den 10.7. herum mal vorbeikommen”).

Besides, *um* can also be used in non-time-circumstances, e.g. as a local preposition or as demanded by a verb.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that "am" derives from "an dem", whereas no such root form exists for "um" (to my knowledge).

Comment: Toscho, @falkb, this post now needs further improvement. I agree that *um* can have the meaning of "about". But I was about rejecting this edit. As it stands now, it sounds like "um" means either "exactly" or "approximately". The logical question that must raise now: how can I determine what's meant. But in nearly all instances you can definitely tell what is meant, because the word "um" rarely (or never?) appears alone when "about" is meant but it's "um herum" (as in the example) or "so um". I think, Toscho, if you agree with the change you should add this to the answer, or rollback if not.

Comment: other prepositions with time of day are "Ab 19 uhr" "Bis 19 Uhr" "seit 19 Uhr" "von 19 bis 20 Uhr"... so almost all time prepositions there are... I think this should be added, since the answer makes it sound as if the versions given are the only ones

Comment: @Toscho: thanks for improving my edit. Now it sounds better.

Comment: I wonder if things like `Ich fahre das Verkehrsschild um.` must be considered in the answer as well... or even `Die Kuh lief um den Teich.`

Comment: @falkb 1. The edits up until now aren't mine. 2. Your examples need not be added, as `um` is part of the verb or local preposition in these.

Comment: @falkb: Wo ist der Kuhliefumdenteich nochmal, in welcher Stadt?

Comment: @Toscho I also found the use of "am" in times of the day in this example: "Die jungen Männer wandern am Mittag."

Comment: @user135711 Yes, but in that case `am Mittag` is not a singular time of the day, but a timeframe around 12.00, like `am Nachmittag` or `am Abend`. If you want to specify exactly 12.00, then you'd use `um Punkt Mittag` and again, you have `um` instead of `am`.

Answer (score 2):

"Um" refers to a point in time. Um 8 Uhr.

"Am" refers to a general time-span. Am Morgen.